# Record and save audio in Android which should not be accessed by other apps?

Tags: android, security, audio

I want to how can I record a sound or audio in android and make sure that it will not be accessed by other apps. The sound recorded through the app should be played by that app only and no other audio playing app should be able to open that audio file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the audio you get from `MediaRecorder` or `AudioRecord` in a file in the directory identified by `getFilesDir()` -- this is private storage for your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I was able to write the file to that location. But, the same app is not able to play back that audio with MediaPlayer. It seems there is a problem playing files in /data directory. Anyway of playing that audio file through MediaPlayer.

Comment: Fixed it by setting FileDescriptor in setDataSource.